# I want to delete a stale files which is >365 days along with print the list of files are deleted in cmd via batchfile(.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

```
forfiles /p "C:\Testing" /s /m *.* /D -365 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

above code just deleting the files which is >365 and didn't show/print anything

Comment: Do you mean something like this: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\Testing" /S /D -365 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE Del /A /F @File 1^>NUL 2^>^&1 ^&^& Echo @Path\""```

Comment: your recommended one is not working , actually am trying to use this bat file in autosys job to capture what is deleting while running, so that am trying to print the stuff in logs file

Comment: So how are you doing that? Your question says "it doesn't show/print anything", but makes no mention of a log file. Your command line did not output to a log file, and neither did mine. It also did not mention atosys, so as you are clearly not using Windows environment, but the Autosys one, and I've never used autosys, the only guess I have for this failure is the variable `%SystemRoot%`. Try replacing both instances with `%WinDir%` and/or `C:\Windows`.